# Inserting images in mailing

Tags: civimail, email, images

When creating a mailing, the draft looks fine, but when sending a test, , the images seem to be in all sorts of strange sizes for some people, as if redefining the size in the draft didn’t happen (the original images are quite large). It looked fine in my inbox, but for 2 people who had to click on “download pictures” those images showed up strange. I don’t know if this can effect it too, but I’m on a Mac and they’re not. All are on Outlook.

I then tried to resize the original image and upload those instead of adjusting the size in the draft by replacing the existing ones, but it didn't help. I noticed the image url leads to a mail chimp gallery, so that might be the problem.

I now want to start from scratch instead of replacing old images, but I don't have an image url to use and so I can't upload the images. When I send images to server or browse server, nothing shows up.

This feels like it should be simple but I have no idea what else to try.

Hel and thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues going on here.  First, you have images that you attempt to resize, but they are appearing wrong for many recipients.  Second, you can't fix the images.

I can't answer the second issue without knowing your particular server environment.  I'm especially puzzled how you got your images up there in the first place but are having trouble now.

However, I can explain the first issue.  When you resize an image in the editor window, all you're doing is adding HTML parameters or inline CSS to constrain the images to a given height or width.  You have to trust the recipient's email client or webmail to carry out your instructions, though.

It's not uncommon for email clients to strip out the inline CSS that scales images, so that's what you're facing.  You're on the right track: get the actual image file to a size that is reasonably close to what you want, and then only trust the editor for fine-tuning.

Comment: To add a question-specific tip here I have found that Outlook does not respect width as civiMail puts it in by default (something like img src="img.jpg" style="width:200px;"). If you're comfortable directly editing the HTML for the email, I have found that Outlook DOES respect the styling of the format style="width:200;" (remove the 'px'). I have also found that it respects style="width:100%;max-width=600px;". Outlook is a real pita in terms of CSS support. Good luck!